# Programatic way to lock screen rotation when app is running?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a programatic way to lock the screen so auto rotation does not happen when my app is running ?, googleing all I can see is howto go into android settings and stop rotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the app manifest set the following attribute for the activity tag if you want portrait:

```
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

and:

```
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```